# Is there a way to convert a MinGW .a file to a msvc lib/dll?

Tags: c++, mingw, .a

I have .a/.dll/.h files generated with MinGW, and I don't have the source code. Now, in order to use it with MSVC, I want to convert it to MSVC lib and dll.

**Is it possible? How to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a dll with C interface then most likely you can use it directly in VS without any modifications (you may still need to generate export library file for it using lib.exe tool). If it is a C++ dll then you will need to wrap it into C interface using mingw first.

Comment: Oops, according to the .h file, it's a C++ dll. Do you mean I can write another MinGW lib (let's say wrapper.a) to wrap it into C interface and then use lib.exe tool to convert the wrapper lib file (wrapper.a) ?

Comment: @ricky Well, in mingw .a files are static libraries. They can not be used in VS at all. However using mingw you can create a .dll with C interface that will link original static or dynamic library (and then create an export lib for VS) that can be used in VS.